# Using Execute() method in Table-valued function SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I am trying to create a table-valued function in SQL Server. My issue is that I can't find the right syntax for the SQL. I keep getting errors. I don't know if it is possible to use an `execute()` method in a table-valued function. I have tried declaring and setting the variables and also using the execute method in an oridinary sql query and it works.

My SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SortRoutePartByDay
(   
    @date datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
Begin
    declare @cmdtext varchar(max)  
    declare @Daynameofweek varchar(10)
    set @Daynameofweek = datename(weekday, @date)
    set @cmdtext =  'select * from RoutePartPart where ' +@Daynameofweek+' =1';

    RETURN 
    (
        execute(@cmdtext)
    )
GO
```

My error so far is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SortRoutePartByDay, Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'execute'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SortRoutePartByDay, Line 23
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

RoutePartPart DDL:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RoutePartPart](
        [RouteID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [RoutePartNo] [smallint] NOT NULL,
        [RoutePartPartNo] [smallint] NOT NULL,
        [PickupAreaGrpID] [int] NULL,
        [DeliveryAreaGrpID] [int] NULL,
        [Monday] [bit] NULL,
        [Tuesday] [bit] NULL,
        [Wednesday] [bit] NULL,
        [Thursday] [bit] NULL,
        [Friday] [bit] NULL,
        [Saturday] [bit] NULL,
        [Sunday] [bit] NULL,
        [Pickup] [bit] NULL,
        [Delivery] [bit] NULL,
        [Types] [varchar](10) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think using dynamic SQL is unnecessary in your case, so try this one -

**Query:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION SortRoutePartByDay
(   
    @date DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN
     SELECT * 
     FROM dbo.RoutePartPart 
     WHERE DATENAME(weekday, @date) = 1
```

**Small info:**

Functions on SQL Server are not the same as stored procedures, they have several limitations on the things that can be done. For example, you can't use dynamic SQL.

**Update:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION SortRoutePartByDay
(   
    @date DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN
     SELECT p.* 
     FROM dbo.RoutePartPart p
     CROSS JOIN (
          SELECT [WeekDay] = DATENAME(weekday, @date)    
     ) t 
     WHERE ([WeekDay] = 'Monday' AND [Monday] = 1)
          OR ([WeekDay] = 'Tuesday' AND [Tuesday] = 1)
          OR ([WeekDay] = 'Wednesday' AND [Wednesday] = 1)
          OR ([WeekDay] = 'Thursday' AND [Thursday] = 1)
          OR ([WeekDay] = 'Friday' AND [Friday] = 1)
          OR ([WeekDay] = 'Saturday' AND [Saturday] = 1)
          OR ([WeekDay] = 'Sunday' AND [Sunday] = 1)
```

Comment: +1 Correct, but maybe try to clarrify what went wrong. The difference between multi/single statement table functions? and Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.

Comment: The @Daynameofweek parameter is a column in the table. This approach will compare the nvarchar value "Thursday" with the int 1. the weekday needs to be a column because i need to get all rows with the value 1.

Comment: @Lahib, OK. Can you provide DDL of your table.